# process multiple files on azure data lake

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

let's assume there are two file sets A and B on azure data lake store.

```
/A/Year/
/A/Month/Day/Month/
/A/Year/Month/Day/A_Year_Month_Day_Hour

/B/Year/
/B/Month/Day/Month/
/B/Year/Month/Day/B_Year_Month_Day_Hour
```

I want to get some values (let's say DateCreated of A entity) and use these values generate file paths for B set.

how can I achieve that?

some thoughts,but i'm not sure about this.
1.select values from A 
2.store on some storage ( azure data lake or azure sql database).
3. build one comma separated string pStr
4. pass pStr via Data Factory to stored procedure which generates file paths with pattern.

**EDIT**

according to @mabasile_MSFT answer

Here is what i have right now.
First USQL script that generates json file, which looks following way.

```
{
FileSet:["/Data/SomeEntity/2018/3/5/SomeEntity_2018_3_5__12",
"/Data/SomeEntity/2018/3/5/SomeEntity_2018_3_5__13",
"/Data/SomeEntity/2018/3/5/SomeEntity_2018_3_5__14",
"/Data/SomeEntity/2018/3/5/SomeEntity_2018_3_5__15"]
}
```

ADF pipeline which contains Lookup and second USQL script.
Lookup reads this json file FileSet property and as i understood i need to somehow pass this json array to second script right?
But usql compiler generates string variable like

DECLARE @fileSet string =  "["/Data/SomeEntity/2018/3/5/SomeEntity_2018_3_5__12",
        "/Data/SomeEntity/2018/3/5/SomeEntity_2018_3_5__13",
        "/Data/SomeEntity/2018/3/5/SomeEntity_2018_3_5__14",
        "/Data/SomeEntity/2018/3/5/SomeEntity_2018_3_5__15"]"

and the script even didn't get compile after it.

Comment: would love to know how you solved this?

Answer (score 2):

You will need two U-SQL jobs, but you can instead use an ADF Lookup activity to read the filesets.

Your first ADLA job should extract data from A, build the filesets, and [output to a JSON file](https://github.com/Azure/usql/tree/master/Examples/DataFormats/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats) in [Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-manage-use-dotnet-sdk).

Then use a [Lookup activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) in ADF to read the fileset names from your JSON file in Azure Storage.

Then define your second U-SQL activity in ADF.  Set the fileset as a parameter (under Script > Advanced if you're using the online UI) in the U-SQL activity - the value will look something like `@{activity('MyLookupActivity').output.firstRow.FileSet}` (see Lookup activity docs above).

ADF will write in the U-SQL parameter as a DECLARE statement at the top of your U-SQL script.  If you want to have a default value encoded into your script as well, use DECLARE EXTERNAL - this will get overwritten by the DECLARE statements ADF writes in so it won't cause errors.

I hope this helps, and let me know if you have additional questions!

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm currently looking into whether you can pass a group of parameters via a look up activity, since using a ForEach loop to iterate over your lookup activity would create too many U-SQL jobs. Until then, would using a [fileset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/input-files-u-sql) work for you? For example, if you always put the new files into a distinct folder and want to read the entire contents of the folder, you can use "/Data/SomeEntity/2018/3/5/{*}" to select all files from that folder.

Answer (score -1):

Try this root link, that can help you start with all about u-sql: 
http://usql.io

Usefull link for your question:
https://saveenr.gitbooks.io/usql-tutorial/content/filesets/filesets-with-dates.html